# Как включить адаптивный дизайн через Selenium + Firefox?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как включить адаптивный дизайн через Selenium + Firefox ?

Вручную включается через Ctrl+Shift+M

не могу понять как через c# + Selenium это сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тут:

https://webdriver.io/docs/options/#capabilities

сказано следующее: Если вы запускаете веб-тесты или собственные тесты на мобильных устройствах, их возможности отличаются от протокола WebDriver. См. Дополнительную информацию в документации Appium (http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)